# Compare two tensors elementwise (tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I have two 1D Tensorflow tensors and I want to compare them elementwise and create a new tensor recording the indices at which they differ. For context, they each store indices into a different, 2D tensor, so if I could use them like numpy arrays I might do something like:

```
for i in range(0, len(predicted_indices)):
    if predicted_indices[i] != correct_indices[i]:
        failed_preds.append(self.input_placeholder[i])
```

but in the case where predicted_indices and correct_indices are both tensors, how can I do this?

Also open to other ways to do this. I'm trying to store the specific examples that my model gets wrong at some epoch.

Comment: are you looking for `tf.equal(prediction, labels)`  which return a bool type tensor indicating the difference between `prediction` and `labels`?

Comment: BTW, `tensorflow` itself provides utils functions to measure the performance of models included in the `tf.metrics` module, take a look at it you might find something useful for you

Comment: It looks like those can tell me ie how many false positives there are, and what I want is which examples are false positives. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

In Tensorflow you build a graph in which you define the operations, before you actually perform the operation. 
In this case the operation you can use is the tf.equal function where you pass your predicted_indices and input_placeholder as arguments. This returns a boolean tensor.

Check the operation and other comparison operations here: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops/comparison_operators#equal

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There are two aspects to this

```
sess1=tf.InteractiveSession()
a=np.random.randint(5,size=(1,10))
b=np.random.randint(5,size=(1,10))

a1=tf.convert_to_tensor(a,dtype=tf.float32)
b1=tf.convert_to_tensor(b,dtype=tf.float32)
```

**Boolean Comparison**

```
print(a1.eval())
print(b1.eval())
result=tf.equal(a1,b1)
print(result.eval())
```

**Element Comparison**

```
print(a1.eval())
print(b1.eval())
result=tf.add(a1,-a2)
print(result.eval())
```

Once you have this, you can use this in any capacity that you want